# Standard way of Importing javascript modules into vue components

Tags: vuejs2, pdf.js

What is the correct way of importing javascript modules into vue-components?

I currently have a vue-component component.js:

```
Vue.component('component', {
    name: 'component',
    props: ['pdf'],
    template: ` ...
```

I want to take a pdf-url as a prop and use pdf.js within the component, but I'm having trouble finding the right way/standard way to import pdf.js into my project.

Worth noting is that I'm not using vue-cli, or any other kind of bundler like Webpack, so my project structure might be a bit different from standard project structures. I access my components from a main.html file in which I have imported both vue and the components in script-tags in the head of the html. Would I simply import pdf.js in the same manner (head in the main.html file), or is there a "vue"-way of doing it?

Comment: _"is there a "vue"-way of doing it?"_ <- one of the best things about Vue is that it is un-opinionated about any other library you want to use

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using webpack or any other packager, then I will recommend you to stick to the old fashion way, just use `pdf.js` as `script` in your html and make use of the API as it is in the official documentation, such as: `pdf.getPage(1).then(...)`

Hope it helps.

Cheers